# SSRS : subreport for each value from some dataset column

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, subreport

I have some report that take 3 parameters:
-@start and @end  for specify the period of salesman's sales
- and @name for the name of salesman.
this rapport work very right. Now, i want to can generate this report for each salesman choosing all name of salesman on some period. i will obtain as match report corresponding the number of salesman.

I want to know how to proceed to do this. thanks for any advice

Comment: What's the actual question? Are you asking us to write the report? If so, there's no information about the structure of your database.

Comment: I would like the procedure to follow, explanation of tools and methods.